# RadGrid Rebind in PageLoad not working properly

Tags: telerik, radgrid

I am doing a Rebind() of a RedGrid on PageLoad.

When I do this, the radGrid does not behave properly. Some examples are that when I do an edit, I cannot close the edit portion or update.

This is also mentioned on the last post at:

```
http://www.telerik.com/forums/radgrid-not-refreshing-after-rebind
```

Just wondering where else I can do a databind if not in the PageLoad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do the Databind in Page_LoadComplete because I need that first execute the ControlsEvents of my User Controls.

Sample:

```
protected void Page_LoadComplete(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = GetQuery();
    SqlDataSource1.DataBind();
    RadGrid1.DataBind();
}
```

If this does not work for you please write a part of your code for try it in my computer.

Comment: Thank you Ferri. This did not fix the problem. Give me sometime. I will put a shortened version of my code so you can easily replicate it